# Can you @ping a user after they have deleted their last comment?

Tags: support, comments, comment-replies, deleted-comments

You can use `@<user>` to ping/notify a user that has commented previously. But if they have deleted their last comment do they still receive notifications if another user @-pings them in the same comment thread? (Bearing in mind that comments are only soft-deleted anyway.)

Comment: Specifically, the 2nd bullet under "Who can be notified with this feature?": "Any user who has a visible (non-deleted) comment on the post."